# Length of String within tags in java

Tags: java, xml, substring

We need to find the length of the tag names within the tags in java
`{Student}{Subject}{Marks}100{/Marks}{/Subject}{/Student}`
so the length of Student tag is 7 and that of subject tag is 7 and that of marks is 5.

I am trying to split the tags and then find the length of each string within the tag.

But the code I am trying gives me only the first tag name and not others.

Can you please help me on this?

I am very new to java. Please let me know if this is a very silly question.

Code part:

```
System.out.println(
    getParenthesesContent("{Student}{Subject}{Marks}100{/Marks}{/Subject}{/Student}"));

public static String getParenthesesContent(String str) {
    return str.substring(str.indexOf('{')+1,str.indexOf('}'));
}
```

Comment: just add a loop, iterate over all matches of '{' '}'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to give a try to another regex:

```
String s = "{Abc}{Defg}100{Hij}100{/Klmopr}{/Stuvw}"; // just a sample String
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{\\W*(\\w++)\\W*\\}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1) + ", length: " + m.group(1).length());
}
```

Output you get:

```
Abc, length: 3
Defg, length: 4
Hij, length: 3
Klmopr, length: 6
Stuvw, length: 5
```

If you need to use `charAt()` to walk over the input String, you might want to consider using something like this (I made some explanations in the comments to the code):

```
String s = "{Student}{Subject}{Marks}100{/Marks}{/Subject}{/Student}";
ArrayList<String> tags = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); // Use StringBuilder and its append() method to append Strings (it's more efficient than "+=")      String appended = ""; // This String will be appended when correct tag is found
    if(s.charAt(i) == '{') { // If start of tag is found...
        while(!(Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i)))) { // Skip characters that are not letters
        i++;
        }
        while(Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i))) { // Append String with letters that are found
            sb.append(s.charAt(i));
            i++;
        }
        if(!(tags.contains(sb.toString()))) { // Add final String to ArrayList only if it not contained here yet
            tags.add(sb.toString());
        }
    }
}
for(String tag : tags) { // Printing Strings contained in ArrayList and their length
    System.out.println(tag + ", length: " + tag.length());
}
```

Output you get:

```
Student, length: 7
Subject, length: 7
Marks, length: 5
```

Comment: Hi Przemysław Moskal, thnks for the information. I was just curious to know, can we use charAt() to get the required output?

Comment: @luciferxxx Yes it is possible, but in this case using Pattern seems to be a much better and concise way. Firsly create an empty String. If you would like to get desired output, you could firstly use check, if charAt is a "{" character. If it is not you check next indexes until you find it. Then check next characters if the are letters with the method isLetter() from Character class. You then append these letters to the String until isLetter() returns false. Add final String to String[] to store them for future purposes. Then you start with checking if charAt() next index is "{" and so on...

Comment: @luciferxxx I made an edit to my answer. I have writren a code that uses `charAt()` method to walk through the String. Please let me know if it is what you were looking for.

Comment: ..Thanks a lot for the new and another approach

Comment: @luciferxxx Glad that I could help you and to exercise it a bit anyway :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Patterns with this regex [`\\{(\[a-zA-Z\]*)\\}`](https://regex101.com/r/ilsSHv/1) :

```
String text = "{Student}{Subject}{Marks}100{/Marks}{/Subject}{/Student}";

Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\{([a-zA-Z]*)\\}").matcher(text);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(
            String.format(
                    "tag name = %s, Length = %d ",
                    matcher.group(1),
                    matcher.group(1).length()
            )
    );
}
```

Outputs

```
tag name = Student, Length = 7 
tag name = Subject, Length = 7 
tag name = Marks, Length = 5
```

Comment: Thanks YCF_L..it was of great help

Answer (score 0):

yes use regular expression, find the pattern and apply that.